# Убрать реверс координат на карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Почему-то точка на карте показывается с не правильными координатами. Широта и долгота меняются местами.
Точка должна показываться под Москвой, но показывается где-то в Туркменистане.

Вот такой объект хранится в БД:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b853ad554a6df2f74e1521e"),
    "_lng" : 37.541123046875,
    "_lat" : 55.4365341403253,
    "_quadKey" : "012300133031210331312322",
    "type" : "Feature",
    "geometry" : {
        "coordinates" : [ 
            55.4365341403253, 
            37.541123046875
        ],
        "type" : "Point"
    },
    "properties" : {
        "hintContent" : "Братиш го катку?",
        "balloonContent" : "Это моя точка"
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Такой объект приходит от сервера:

```
/**/ typeof id_15354585506921833971 === 'function' && id_15354585506921833971({
  "error": null,
  "data": {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            55.43653414032533,
            37.541123046874986
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "balloonContent": "Это моя точка",
          "hintContent": "Братиш го катку?"
        },
        "id": "5b853ad554a6df2f74e1521e"
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

Вот код отображения данных:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>Пример работы с RemoteObjectManager.</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <link href="//yandex.st/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="//yandex.st/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru-RU&coordorder=longlat&mode=debug"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        ymaps.ready(function () {
            var myMap = window.map = new ymaps.Map('YMapsID', {
                center: [37.573856, 55.751574],
                zoom: 6
            }, {
                // minZoom: 5
            });

            var objectManager = new ymaps.RemoteObjectManager('/api/v1/features/within/tiles?bbox=%t&clusterize=1&zoom=%z', {
                // Опции кластеров задаются с префиксом cluster.
                clusterHasBalloon: false,
                // Опции геообъектов задаются с префиксом geoObject
                // geoObjectOpenBalloonOnClick: false,
                // splitRequests: true
            });

            myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #YMapsID {
            width: 900px;
            height: 480px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hero-unit">
        <div class="container">
            <p>Серверная кластеризация с помощью ymaps.RemoteObjectManager и NodeJS + MongoDB.</p>
            <div id="YMapsID"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вы подключаете карту с параметром coordorder=longlat, именно он отвечает за то какая координата первая, а какая вторая

Comment: @PavelGorobtsov Спасибо, похоже помогло.